# Extract variable length text within string using Javascript

Tags: javascript, string

I am trying to extract a couple of fields from a string.

**String (str)**

```
OBX|10|TX|||Patient:  DOE,JOHN   Acct #:  1234567890   DOB:  01/01/1960
```

I am trying to get the **Patient** name which is variable in length and the **DOB**.

I have the following, but am stuck with the variable length of the patient.

```
patientName = str.slice(str.indexOf("Patient: ")+11, 20)
```

Comment: Have you considered a regular expression?

Comment: _"with the variable length of the patient"_ - If you already use a "magic word" to find the name (`"Patiern: "`) then why don't you use another (`"Acct: "`) to find the "end" of the name?

Comment: @Andreas Thanks! `str.slice(str.indexOf("Patient: ")+9, str.indexOf("Acct #:"))`

Comment: Are you worried about malicious users who try to confuse your code by registering with weird names?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prevent using the exact index numbers, you could alternatively use a pattern with 2 capture groups for the Patient name and DOB:

```
\bPatient:\s*(.+?)\s*Acct #:.*\bDOB:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\b
```

In parts the pattern matches:

- `\bPatient:\s*` Match `Patient:` followed by optional whitespace chars
- `(.+?)` Capture 1+ times any char non greedy in **group 1**
- `\s*Acct #:.*` Match optional whitespace chars and `Acct #:` and optionally any char
- `(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\b` Capture in **group 2** a date like pattern

```js
const regex = /\bPatient:\s*(.+?)\s.*\bDOB:\s*(\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4})\b/;
const s = "OBX|10|TX|||Patient:  DOE,JOHN   Acct #:  1234567890   DOB:  01/01/1960";
const m = s.match(regex);
if (m) {
  console.log(`Patient: ${m[1]} and DOB: ${m[2]}`);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with regex:

Assuming there will be no numbers in the name string, use this 1st regex for name:

`(Patient:)(\s*)(\D*)(\s*)(Acct)`

and you can use this other one for DOB:

`(DOB:)(\s*)(\S*)(\s)`

Here is the javascript code for it:

```
const regex = /(DOB:)(\s*)(\S*)(\s)/gm;
const str = `OBX|10|TX|||Patient:  DOE,JOHN   Acct #:  1234567890   DOB:  01/01/1960 `;
let m;

while ((m = regexDOB.exec(str)) !== null) {
    // This is necessary to avoid infinite loops with zero-width matches
    if (m.index === regex.lastIndex) {
        regex.lastIndex++;
    }
    
    // The result can be accessed through the `m`-variable.
    m.forEach((match, groupIndex) => {
        console.log(`Found match, group ${groupIndex}: ${match}`);
    });
}
```

You can also do one single regex to get it all in the same expression. I just decided to split in 2 like this so the expressions are simpler to read so you can get the idea on how they work :)

Comment: `(Patient:)(\s*)(\D*)(\s*)(Acct)` doesn't work as you expected: `\D*` is a greedy match that can match spaces, which means the capture group includes the spaces after the name, and not just the name as intended.